# Android Firebase - upload image from drawable to storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get an image from drawable folder and save it on Firebase Storage.
To save the image im using `UploadTask` and it require a Uri file.
The image from drawable is int. There is anyway to convert that int into Uri?

**Check out my code please**

```
 private void saveProfileImgToStorage(final User user) {
    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    StorageReference userImgProfile = storageRef.child("/usersProfiles/" + currentUser.getUid() +"/profile_image");
    UploadTask uploadTask;

          //What should i do here??
          //This is the path of the image "R.drawable.ic_account"
    uploadTask = userImgProfile.putFile();

    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Uri firebaseURL = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            user.setProfilePic(firebaseURL.toString());
            uploadToFirebaseDatabase(user);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit**

Found the solution

```
   //This how i should write it - and now it works!
  Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ R.class.getPackage().getName()+"/"+R.drawable.profile_image);
   UploadTask uploadTask;

    uploadTask = userImgProfile.putFile(imageUri);
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the uri from an image stored into drawable simply do this

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.ic_account);
```

a little bit cleaner

```
 Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + 
 R.drawable.ic_account);
```

Where `context` can be `this` if you refer to an Activity or `getActivity()` from a Fragment.

To upload it to Firebase you will need to do this

```
File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
```

and then

```
uploadTask = userImgProfile.putFile(file);
```

Comment: For some reason, it tells me that "No package found for authority", and i did exacly like you

Comment: did you tried the second one ? it will fetch the package by itself, also where it says your.package.name you should put your package name

Comment: I did the second answer, and this what it gives me `0663-21280/com.world.bolandian.talent E/StorageException: No package found for authority: android.resource://com.world.bolandian.talent2131231132
                                                                              java.io.FileNotFoundException: No package found for authority: android.resource://com.world.bolandian.talent2131231132`

Comment: The method `getpath` is not available. But are you sure its the answer? because its cant find the image path. i think i need somehow to change the path

Comment: i think it worked, but now im getting other error, `could not retrieve file size for upload file` . i think the image size is too big

Comment: yep, make sure its not very big , you can get that image from drawable , transform it into a bitmap, compress it and make the file, if the answer helped you you can mark it as correct